# Use django rest framework to parse server response

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have DRF. I want to make a get call with `requests` library, get json, parse it with one of my serializers and save to database.

Is it possible to pass json array to serializer and save to db ?

Answer (score 1):

Requests already gives you a `dict` if you want it, so there is no need to parse.  Just call `.json()` and pass that directly into the serializer.

The saving of your objects is a separate issue; you can do it in the serializer or do it manually in your view using the validated data from the serializer.

```
resp = requests.get('http://my-service')
if resp.status_code == 200:        
    ser = MySerializerClass(data=resp.json()) # the .json() parses to a dict
    ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    # save using the serializer, if you've implemented there
    ser.save() 

    # -or- do it manually
    data = ser.validated_data
    MyModel.objects.create(name=data['name', etc)
```

Note that nested serializers are a whole different topic, and not easy to implement well.  Personally, I would create the objects manually from the validated_data (either in the method or in `.save`) in that case, using [transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly)